# Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_dev_server_client__ is not defined

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, webpack

running our build artifact from *S3* through *CloudFront* we get `Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_dev_server_client__ is not defined`, the error does not reproduce locally.
We build our script in CodeBuild.
The *CodeBuild* image is `aws/codebuild/nodejs:10.14.1-1.7.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Until they push a fix, you can install an older version:

```
npm uninstall webpack-dev-server --save-dev

npm install webpack-dev-server@3.5.1 --save-dev
```

Solution found here https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2006#issuecomment-500419258

Comment: Version 3.5.1 still not helping